# Issue with Class Inheritance

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.4

I'm trying to create a class that extends HTTPBasicAuthHandler. For some reason the same approach I use in older code is not working here.

```
class AuthInfo(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler):
    def __init__(self, realm, url, username, password):
        self.pwdmgr     = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        self.pwdmgr.add_password(None, url, username, password)
        super(AuthInfo, self).__init__(self.pwdmgr)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./RestResult.py", line 67, in ?
    auth = AuthInfo(None, "default", "xxxxx", "xxxxxxxx")
  File "./RestResult.py", line 47, in __init__
    super(AuthInfo, self).__init__(self.pwdmgr)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* error. There must be a line after the ones you quoted...

Comment: To extend on what glglgl said: You left out the most important line of the exception: the last one! This line tells us what kind of error you are getting when executing the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler` class is an old-style class (it doesn't inherit from `object`), which means it can't be used with `super`. You have to call its `__init__` directly instead:

```
urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler.__init__(self, self.pwdmgr)
```

Comment: `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler`

Comment: @dano: Someone once suggested to me to - in such cases - simply inherit from both `object` *and* the old-style class. That looks a bit dodgy to me. But then again, I have a strong Java history ;) Thoughts on that?

Comment: @exhuma I think that will work ok with basic child-parent inheritence as long as you always inherit from object last: `class AuthInfo(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler, object):`. I'm not sure if it will always do the right thing in multiple-inheritance situations, though, since you don't have a true diamond. (Not all classes  inherit from a common base - which is normally `object`).